# How to insert a NEWID() / GUID / UUID into the code editor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Many code editors have a built-in menu item or keyboard function to get a UUID, for example when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in Delphi it inserts a GUID at the current position in the source code.

I know that I can use `SELECT NEWID()` to generate a UUID, but I have to go to the query result, copy the generated UUID to my clipboard (killing whatever was in there before) and then go back to the code and replace the query which is an awful way of dealing with this.

Is there any function (maybe using IntelliSense code snippets?) to do this in SQL Server Management Studio that I haven't found yet?

Some background on why I need this function, I often write SQL Scripts like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (table_id, value) 
VALUES ('112C8DD8-346B-426E-B06C-75BBA97DCD63', 'ABC');
```

I can't use just call `NEWID()`, because I later (in another file) want to refer to the specific row using:

```
WHERE table_id = '112C8DD8-346B-426E-B06C-75BBA97DCD63'
```

How can I insert a UUID into the code editor?

Comment: You can just add code snippet that print select newid() (Tools->Code Snippets Manager) and call it with ctrl+k+s or ctrl+k+x not more...

Comment: @user3623784 SMSS won't evaluate `SELECT NEWID()`, but will just copy the code into my code which is not what I want.

Comment: And this is where I suggested to use a Variable to capture the value of NEWID() and later use that variable to do further manipulation.

Comment: BTW: The two SQL commands are in different files, so a variable won't work. If a UUID is required twice in the same script a variable is of course the reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`NEWID()` itself is a function. when called returns a GUID value.

You do not have to put it in a separate window and then copy paste value from there. Just simply put that function there where you want the GUID value and when the query is executed at run time the value returned by this function will be used.

For instance in an Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Col1 , Col2, Col3)
VALUES (1 , 'Value 1', NEWID())
```

If you want col3 to have a GUID value you do not need to copy paste the value returned from NEWID() function but you use the function itself. At runtime a guid value will be retuned and inserted into col3.

Similarly if you were updating

```
UPDATE TableName 
  SET Col3 = NEWID()
WHERE <Some Condition>
```

Again you dont have to copy paste the value returned from NEWID() function just use the function itself.

Another Option would be suppose you are somewhere inside your code where you cannot call the `NEWID()` function . You would Declare a variable of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER call the function store its value to that variable and then use that variable inside you code something like ...

```
DECLARE @GUID_Value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
 SET @GUID_Value = NEWID();

-- Now use this variable anywhere in your code.
```

### Adding to Keyboard Shortcut

For some strange reason if you want to add a shortcut to your SSMS to generate GUIDs for you. You would need to two thing.

1. Create a stored Procedure which returns GUID value .
2. Add a key shortcut to call that stored Procedure.

### Proc Definition

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_Guid
AS 
 SELECT NEWID();
```

### Add it to shortcuts

From your SSMS goto Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard

add the stored procedure's name to the shortcut you want to. Click OK. Close SSMS and reopen it again and you are good to go.

[image]

As shown in the above snipshot, now if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>0</kbd> it will generate a GUID value for you in the same query window.

Comment: +1 Also I just found out that you can drag & drop the generated UUID from the query result tab to the code editor. This works for me :)

Comment: when i run newid() in my sql query it's giving an error stating ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION wallet_payout.newid does not exist. Any idea why?

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn Use dbo.newid() then.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL server, and maybe others.

One can insert a string-encoded Guid/uuid in SQL server using the convert function.  See the zeroed Guid in the example below.

```
INSERT INTO [schema].[table]
           ([Id]
           ,[stuff])
     VALUES
           (Convert(uniqueidentifier, N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
           ,'Interesting Stuff'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **SQL Prompt** extension installed, you can create a new snippet like so...

**Snippet:** `guid`

**Description:** `new GUID`

**Code:**

```
'$GUID$'
```

Now type `guid` in your text editor and you'll get a new GUID surrounded by `'`s.