# Insert GUID into sql table uniqueidentifier field - Groovy

Tags: java, sql, groovy

With the following table how would I insert a Guid value into the guidField of the table. Using the following groovy code results in the following error "because: The name "B551F2C8" is not permitted in this context." Guid generated is B551F2C8-8380-491B-A51F-436E51CDD08F. Maybe the '-' in the Guid are the problem. Any ideas?

SQL table

```
create table tblTest  
(
  guidField  uniqueidentifier,
  strField  varchar(50),
  dateField smalldatetime
)
```

Code block

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
long lTimeStamp = d.getTime();
String tableInsert = "INSERT INTO tblTest (guidField,strField,dateField)" +
                                  " VALUES ("   + uuid +
                                            "," + 'test' +
                                            "," + lTimeStamp +
                                            ")";
sql.execute(tableInsert);
```

Comment: Use parameters instead of munging the query string.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315207/how-to-insert-a-newid-guid-uuid-into-the-code-editor)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help since that's done from the database side. I'm trying to send a UUID to the database table from within a groovy script and I'm not sure how to satisfy the insert for the uniqueidentifier. I guess no one knows how, which seems weird.

Comment: Gordan and Felipe answer are good.
Use parameter, or put GUID into '' (single quote)

...('" + uuid + "'" ...

Comment: How would I use a parameter method for this. I'm new to SQL and don't really know about the parameter passing option for this. Can someone help me understand that further by providing an example?

btw, uuid is a variable, see the example code above, so putting it into single quotes will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
//long lTimeStamp = d.getTime();
String tableInsert = "INSERT INTO tblTest (guidField,strField,dateField)" +
                              " VALUES ('" + uuid + "'"
                                        ",'test'" +
                                        ", getdate()"
                                        ")";
sql.execute(tableInsert);
```

Do you need your guid into your application?  If not, let SQL server generate one for you :

```
String tableInsert = "INSERT INTO tblTest (guidField,strField,dateField)" +
                              " VALUES (newid()"
                                        ",'test'" +
                                        ", getdate()"
                                        ")";
sql.execute(tableInsert);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this helped me see the problem =) I didn't realize the uniqueidentifier is essentially a string and needed to be in quotes =)  This works now String tableInsert = "INSERT INTO tblTest (guidField,strField,dateField)" +
        " VALUES ('" + uuid + "'" + "," + "'test'" + "," + new Date().getDate() + ")"; Thanks for the visual answer.